# WFFM - Is it possible to change the theme per site?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, web-forms-for-marketers, multisite

In WFFM, you can create your own theme which is set globally for the site on the Website folder (system/modules/web forms for marketers/Website).
I have a custom theme working and my theme is loads correctly when I change the Theme field on the global Website folder. 
The issue is that I have a multi-site instance and the Theme needs to change based on the site. Currently I created subfolders but the page only reads the theme set on the global Website folder instead of the subfolders.

[image]

I haven't run across any documentation on setting up WFFM this way, anyone had any experience with setting up multi-site themes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the root form folder in your `<site>` definition, by default the forms.config file specifies the following, which points to `/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Website`:

```
<sites>
  <site name="website">
    <patch:attribute name="formsRoot">{F1F7AAB6-C8CE-422F-A214-F610C109FA63}</patch:attribute>
  </site>
</sites>
```

In a multi-site instance you need to specify the `formsRoot` attribute for each site:

```
<sites>
  <site name="site1" ... formsRoot="/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Website/Website 1" />
  <site name="site2" ... formsRoot="/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Website/Website 2" />
</sites>
```

The path should work, if it does not then use the Item ID.

Make sure the folders are of template type `/sitecore/templates/Web Forms for Marketers/Forms Folder` and you should be able to set the Theme property for each site separately. Take a look at section 2.10 of the [Webforms For Marketers Reference Guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/web_forms2/25/web%20forms%20for%20marketers%20v2_5%20reference-a4.pdf).

Comment: This is correct. But be aware that in the currect version (2.4 rev.141008), Themes are not working when using MVC layouts.
Sitecore Support has registered this as a bug.